# AngularJS : How to watch a service object

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs, kendo-ui

I have tried using different examples with the watch function, but I am not able to make it work. I am watching a service that contains a array of objects, each object contains a array of arrays. I need to watch the array of arrays for changes.

JSON

```
 [{
    "name": "Chantal Hamlet - Green Castle Homes",
    "subId": "10223",
    "bldId": "13551",
    "data": [
        [179900, 1386],
        [214900, 1440],
        [194500, 1496],
        [217900, 1504],
        [189900, 1542],
        [184900, 1546],
        [192500, 1570],
        [189900, 1576],
        [191900, 1598],
        [204900, 1626],
        [219900, 1651],
        [212900, 1704],
        [214900, 1787],
        [219900, 1837],
        [224900, 1857]
    ]
 }, {
     "name": "Ella Sea Condos - Sahnow Construction",
     "subId": "9761",
     "bldId": "27380",
     "data": [
         [199900, 1500]
     ]
 }]
```

Watch function

```
$scope.$watchCollection(function () {
    return chartService.series
},
function (rawData) {
    $scope.seriesData = rawData;
});
```

Service

```
chart.factory('chartService', function () {
return {
    getSeries: function () {
       return this.series;
    },
    setSeries: function (series) {
        this.series = series;
    },
```

Comment: show the service code also

Comment: But is `chartService.series` public? Or are you supposed to get it throught `getSeries`?

Comment: I'm curious why you need to watch at this collection. Using watch in angularJS is often a miss-use.

Comment: @SergiuParaschiv I believe it is public, I just took over project and thought I would use getSeries as well.

Comment: @Okazari what i use a broadcast? I am watching for new data points to update my kendo-ui chart.

Comment: Yeah broadcast is a cleaner way to do this kind of things in my opinion. Did you actually tried it ?

Comment: no, not yet. How would i do it? I would do set the service to a broadcast and then listen with on function? can u show me the best way. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that your setSeries function is changing the object that's being watched.

Think of it like

chartService.series = ObjectA

Watch ObjectA

chartService.series = ObjectB

ObjectA has not changed.

To fix this you need to wrap it in a larger object that doesn't change.

```js
angular.module('chartModule', [])
.controller("chartController", ['$scope', 'chartService',
  function($scope, chartService) {
    $scope.seriesData = chartService.seriesContainer;


    $scope.changeData = function() {
      chartService.seriesContainer.series = [{
        "name": "New Name",
      }];
    }
  }
]).factory('chartService', function() {
  return {
    getSeries: function() {
      return this.series;
    },
    setSeries: function(series) {
      this.series = series;
    },
    seriesContainer: {
      series: [{
        "name": "Chantal Hamlet - Green Castle Homes",
      }]
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<body ng-app="chartModule">
  <div ng-controller="chartController">
    {{seriesData.series[0].name}}
    <button ng-click="changeData()">Change Data</button>
  </div>
</body>
```

If you use a wrapper you actually don't even need a watch, it will happen automatically